# How to get rid of 'property could not be set to a double value, you must set this property to a non-null value of type decimal'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to get a function import to work correctly.  EF calls out to my stored procedure, but the result has an inner exception that I don't understand:

```
var result = context.SomeFunctionImport();
```

I get:

> The 'Cnt' property on 'SomeClass' could not be set to a 'Double'
>   value.  You must set this property to a non-null value of type
>   'Decimal'.

Here's the `Cnt` property on `SomeClass`:

```
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<decimal> Cnt
    {
        get { return _cnt; }
        set
        {
            if (_cnt != value)
            {
                OnComplexPropertyChanging();
                _cnt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Cnt");
            }
        }
    }
    private Nullable<decimal> _cnt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue.  My stored procedure was missing a cast on Cnt after a rounding operation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define it like this: `public decimal Cnt`

Comment: Is the `value` `nullable` too?

Comment: the value returned from the stored procedure can be null, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I think this field is float type in your database table.
so you need to set it double? if this field is nullable or otherwise use double

```
public double? field_name {get; set}
// or 
public double field_name {get; set}
```

It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my issue was that on the DB, the type was real and in the EF class was declared as decimal. I just changed the DB type to real and problem solved.