# Why entity framework try to convert Guid ids to decimal?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It's the first time I meet a problem like that and I can't find any information about it on the web.

The code below works well

```
Exception_Perimetre = dc.Exception_Perimetre
                      .Where(x => x.Con_Con_Id == ConId
                               && x.Exp_Date_Debut <= date 
                               && x.Exp_Date_Fin >= date)
                      .ToArray();
```

but after random uses, it throw the following exception :

> Property "Exp_Id" to "Exception_Perimetre" could not be set to a value "Decimal". You must assign a non-null value of type 'Guid' to this property.

The original value type is Guid but for some reason Entity framework try to convert it to decimal...

For information, if I use a windows identity connection on IIS, it works well.
It's started to fails after i change to anonymous connection, hoping this part can help someone to find the solution ;)

Comment: What is the type of ConId?

Comment: Decimal type but the where clause don't seem to impact the result

Comment: So Con_Con_Id is Guid and ConId is Decimal?

Comment: No Con_Con_Id is decimal too.

Comment: Okay, but Exp_Id is of type Guid?

Comment: Yes exp_id is the primary key when con_con_id is a foreign key and con_id just a parameter

Comment: Really awkward! Can you show us the whole implementation of your method?

Comment: There's nothing more in my method.

Comment: I return the result "Exception_Perimetre". Can this problem be linked with a static context?

Comment: I see no `Exp_Id` in your code. Probably you should show us more relevant code.

Comment: The Exp_Id is contained in the class Exception_Perimetre generated by Entity Framework.

Comment: which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: The version 5.0.0. After many tests it appears that the problem disapear when i use a non static context. So i think it's liked but i don't know why... Thanks for you're help.

Comment: Found similar question here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851696/how-to-get-rid-of-property-could-not-be-set-to-a-double-value-you-must-set-thi][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851696/how-to-get-rid-of-property-could-not-be-set-to-a-double-value-you-must-set-thi

Comment: Not similar because his problem is a man error (his PS) when in my case it's a problem from EF, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Provide more details if you want to get a better answer. Show the types of all the variables in the snippet by providing the definition of the Exception_Perimetre class (either by the underlying table or generated code).

Personally though I would check to make sure that this isn't a bug in EF that is causing the return value to be forced out instead of the result or perhaps simply in the case that there are no results.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't show the models involved, the way the DbContext is instantiated, or the ConnectionString, all of which might contribute to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when the same context is used from multiple threads. DbContext and ObjectContext ARE NOT thread safe and should not be used in multiple threads. My guess is that  your context is being returned by an IoC provider like StructureMap and the dependency is setup incorrectly to return the same Context for all requests.

Why did this work when authentication was set to Windows Identity? Because the connection string being used was essentially different for each user so there was no sharing of the same open connection across users. When you switched to anonymous, all the sudden each user looked the same and so the context ended up sharing the same shared connection pool.

The reason this only shows up intermittently is because of the multi-threading concern. Essentially what was happening was the Connection was handing back a Reader for request X but is being consumed by request Y. Request Y expected column ordinal 1 to be Guid, but column for request X is a Decimal.

Again, I believe your fix will be to address your IoC configuration or however it is that you're returning an instance of your Context.

I hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: If you are right, and I suspect you are, that's some clever guesswork, given how little relevant information the OP provided.